# Delete Duplicate X values and corresponding Y values

Tags: excel

Is there an easy way to delete an entire row if the X value is a duplicate? As an example, I need an easy way to turn a table like:

```
1  1

1  2

2  2

2  3

3  3

3  4
```

Into a table that deletes duplicate X values and their corresponding Y values:

```
 1 1

 2 2

 3 3
```

I have fiddled with the filter to delete duplicate records (duplicate rows), or deleting duplicate X values. But when I delete duplicate X values, the corresponding Y value no longer matches up with the X value.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data, and assuming that the X values are in column A and the Y values are in column B, and that the data starts in row 2 (because row 1 is a header row), use this formula in cell C2 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1
```

Then filter for `TRUE` values and delete the visible rows.  Afterwards you can clear the C column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Click *anywhere inside the table* > Table Tools (Design) > Tools > Remove Duplicates > tick *the 1st column* > ok